# Exclude strings containing a particular string without using filter function - Python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I was trying to exclude strings containing a particular string without using filter function. For example:

```
/abc/mno/pqr/uvw.py
/abc/mno/rst/uvw.py
/abc/mno/pqr/uvw.c
/abc/mno/vwx/rst.c
/abc/mno/pqr/xyz.java
```

The expected output is all .py and .java paths except the one containing substring '/rst/' or '/vwx/'. That is,

```
/abc/mno/pqr/uvw.py
/abc/mno/pqr/xyz.java
```

I tried:

```
x = re.findall("^(?!.*/rst/|/vwx/.*)\.py|^(?!.*/rst/|/vwx/.*)\.java", txt)
```

But I did not get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SBV3Sl/1)):

```
^(?!.*/rst/.*|.*/vwx/.*).*(?:\.py|\.java)$
```